# How to use Jijna2 unique filter

Tags: python, for-loop, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to only display unique results through jinja for loop. I have

```
{% for i in items %}
    {{ i.item_name | unique }}
{% endfor %}
```

I receive this error: **jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'unique'**. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i am assuming items is a list..if you want only unique why no do it before rendering the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT

`unique` was added in version `2.10`. You can check the [change log](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/changelog/) and the [PR](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/469).

To upgrade your jinja2 version, you can do:

```
pip install --upgrade jinja2
```

---

This works for me in version `2.10`, applying the filter directly to the list:

```
from jinja2 import Template


template = Template("""
  {% for x in a|unique %}
    <li>{{ x }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
""")

r = template.render(a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 4])

print(r)
```

Output:

```
<li>1</li>

<li>2</li>

<li>3</li>

<li>4</li>

<li>5</li>
```

Comment: Ok. What version of jinja are you using?

Comment: i'm using jinja2.8

Comment: I've updated my answer. Seems you need at least `2.10`.